# i want to pass value of var file_id in appended html in href but it consider as a string

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, laravel

```
<div id="invite_popup">
                        
     </div> 
    
    $(".invite_button2").click(function(){
        var file_id = $(this).data("id");
    
        //alert(file_id);
    
    var popup2 ='<div id="invite_popup2" class="accourdians_poup invite_popup2">'+
                    '<ul>'+
                      '<li><a href="#">Rename</a></li>'+
                      '<li><a href="{{ route("dashboard.deletefile", ["file_id"=>'+file_id+']) }}">Delete</a></li>'+
                      '<li><a href="{{ route("dashboard.downloadfile", ["file_id"=>'+file_id+']) }}">download</a></li>'+
                    '</ul>'+
                  '<div>';
    
        $("#invite_popup").append(popup2);
    
    
        $(".invite_popup2").show();
    
      });
```

when am click on `<a> delete</a>`
it shows me like: http://localhost/driveProject/deletefile/+file_id+
i want to print value of file_id in url.
please help me i'll be very thankfull.

Comment: `{{ route("....")}}` is Blade code, rendered server side. Where do you get the `data-id` parameter from?

Comment: <img src="{{ asset('images/accordian_dotted.png') }}" class="invite_button2" data-id="{{ $files->id }}">

Comment: data id get from <img src="{{ asset('images/accordian_dotted.png') }}" class="invite_button2" data-id="{{ $files->id }}">

Comment: Instead of trying to mix Blade/JS try adding the complete url: use something like `data-deleteurl="{{ route("dashboard.deletefile", ["file_id"=> $files->id]) }}"` in your Blade file and adjust your JS accordingly

Answer (score 0):

```
let del = '<li><a href="{{route('dashboard.deletefile')}}?file_id='+file_id+'">Delete</a></li>';
```

Hope you've got the idea

Comment: @meharahmad the last quote should be single quote. Check updated answer and then tell me what error shows Console in Chrome (F12, Console tab)? Or what url you get?